# How do I assign a new keyboard shortcut in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I need a keyboard shortcut for Merge & Center.  I'd like it to be <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.  I am unfamiliar with Macros as was suggested in another answer and when I go to Options, I can't find shortcuts...I tried to follow the Help info, but as was already answered the Excel Customize Ribbon doesn't have the same options that Word 2010 does.

So, how do I go about it step by step?  I know this is for superuser...and I'm not one...but I hope to be one some day.  Please help me on the way.

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/212583/how-do-you-customize-excel-2010-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

There are some built in shortcuts. You can press `ALT` then `H` then `M` then `C`.

Or to use less keystokes, you can right click on the "Merge & Center" button and click "Add to Quick Access Toolbar" and then use `ALT` followed by whatever position it is in the toolbar (by default 4).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Alt + Enter`.                               .

Well, what it really does is 'repeat last action'.

So if your last action was to click 'merge and center' button, alt enter will repeat it - otherwise it will repeat something else (like create new sheet, make text bold or whatever was done lately).

Some would call it a bug, others undocumented feature.

Comment: Would you care to expand on your answer

Comment: What it actually does is 'repeat previous action', pretty much like `F4` or `Ctrl-Y`'. I was misled by clicking the 'merge and center' button, and then trying `Alt-Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not *that* difficult to assign a macro to `ctrl-shift-m`. No VBA is necessary for that.

- Start recording a macro (service | macros | start recording a macro),
- press `shift-m` so that it is assigned to `ctrl-shift-m`,
- click 'merge and center',
- end recording a macro (click an icon with a blue square).

That's it.