# How do you change the Ctrl+Enter keyboard shortcut in Outlook 2007?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Outlook 2007 on Windows XP for work, and always hit `Ctrl+Shift+D` to send messages. That's the shortcut in Mail.app and in MobileMe's Mail web app, and I prefer it to `Ctrl+Enter`, which is Outlook's send mail shortcut. Spoiled by Mac OS X's ability to easily change shortcuts for any application, I've been looking for a way to change the shortcut. How can you do this?

**Update**

I ended up using TeX HeX's suggestion, AutoHotkey. The script I wrote is below:

```
; Remap Ctrl+Shift+D to Ctrl+Enter for Outlook in Message window
#IfWinActive, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
^+d::
Send ^{enter}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option in Outlook to change these `Ctrl+SOMETHING` shortcuts, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/212583/how-do-you-customize-excel-2010-keyboard-shortcuts).

However, you could use AutoHotKey to assign a script that sends `CTRL+ENTER` to Outlook when you press `CTRL+SHIFT+D` - here's a [description of these hotkeys in AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Comment: AutoHotKey. It can cure world hunger.

Comment: @surfasb: That's how it seems. I'm not sure I'll be able to install it on the machine though, as I'm fairly certain I don't have admin access on that box.

Comment: It can also be used as a portable app.  Hear Hear!  http://portableapps.com/node/13021

Comment: I couldn't install it (and I couldn't use it as a "portable app" because the machine in question is a VM I access with Citrix), but I downloaded it as a ZIP, and was able to use it that way, just running in its own directory. I copied a shortcut to my .ahk script (see above) into the Startup folder.