# How to customize Paste Value Excel Short Cut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, copy-paste

I was reading in [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/212583/how-do-you-customize-excel-2010-keyboard-shortcuts?answertab=active#tab-top) how to set up VBA code to paste values in Excel. I understand how to create the VBA code.

I would like to set the keyboard shortcut to Ctrl d but Excel pops up an error and says this is taken when I try to utilize that.

The other post alludes to the idea that you can overwrite these or create/edit VAB code that will let you use Ctrl d without Excel knowing it is different.

I am using Excel 2010 on a PC.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the error? I just checked with Excel 2010 and was able to assign Ctrl+D as a shortcut to my macro just fine. What does pressing Ctrl+D do for you? Perhaps you've already assigned it to another macro?

Comment: Ctrl + D is used by Excel. it copies the cell above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to get a macro assigned, an alternative is to either a) assign a button to your ribbon (I use that all the time), or, b) if it has to be a keyboard solution (I, too, like keyboard shortcuts), SuperUser Doug Glancy answers this with the shortcut that already exists in Excel (along with other great info) in his post:

https://superuser.com/a/212632/221128

"2.Ones like Alt-E-S-V for Edit > Paste Special > Values "  (and then press Enter)