# How can I assign Excel keyboard shortcuts for macros that use keys other than Ctrl + {alpha character}

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I would like to assign keyboard shortcuts to Excel macros that use keys other than the standard Ctrl + {alpha character}. Based on this post it sounds like it is possible but I am not sure how:

> There are 3 different kinds of keyboard shortcuts I know of:
>
> 1. Ones like Ctrl-C for Copy
> 2. Ones like Alt-E-S-V for Edit > Paste
> 3. Special > Values A shortcut key combo you assign to your own macro
>      . . .
>      With #3 it's still the same as it was in earlier versions, just go
>      into the Macro dialog and change the shortcut in Options. You only
>      have the choice of Ctrl and one key, I believe. With VBA you can
>      actually create longer combos like Ctrl-Shft-N (one of my favorites).

[Link to original](https://superuser.com/a/212632/431855)

Doug, would you mind providing additional detail?

Comment: That's a 4 1/2 year old post.  Doug hasn't visited the site in almost a year.  Can you explain what aspect you're having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OnKey** to assign a macro to just about any single keystroke.  See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbHYJOvdv8s

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.