# Editing Excel "Function key" shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365, shortcuts

I was wondering if there is any way in Excel to change for example <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut (Edit cell) to some other key or combination of keys.

I'm working on laptop and I'm using <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys for brightness, volume etc. and don't want to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> because its kinda far apart. Idealy I'd like to change <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> works in place of <kbd>F2</kbd> on some versions, but that's probably just as bad as <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Your machine may also provide an <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd>, which could be worth looking up.

As for actually changing your shortcuts, [it's not trivial](https://superuser.com/q/212583/865660).